# Complex Polynomial That is n Times Differentiable: A Concern

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, induction

I'm looking at a question that asks me to show that:

> If a function $f$ is known to be $n$-times differentiable in a domain $D$ and if $\forall{z\in{D}}\ \ f^{(n)}(z)=0$, then $f$ is a polynomial function of $z$ whose degree is at most $n-1$.

There is a hint to use induction.

My concern is that, in order to do this, I believe I must first show that $f$ is a polynomial and no other function, otherwise I won't be able to use the inductive step that I believe I should take.

Proceeding as such, I can write $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$, so $f^{(n)}(z)=u_{x^{n}}(x,y)+iv_{x^n}(x,y)=0$ which means that $u_{x^n}(x,y)=u_{y^n}(x,y)=0$ and $v_{x^n}(x,y)=v_{y^n}(x,y)=0$ and the equality of the partials given by the Cauchy-Riemann Equations follow because of the differentiability of $0$. If this were just calculus and this function were restricted to $\mathbb{R^2}$, then I would be able to integrate the $u$ and $v$ here to demonstrate that it is a polynomial, but since this is restricted to a domain $D$ and I'm dealing a complex function, I'm not sure if I can still do that.

If I consider the Cauchy-Riemann Equations, then I don't know if I can integrate the real valued functions $u$ and $v$ given by $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hard part is the base case, $n=1$:

> If $f'=0$ in $D$, then $f$ is constant.

Once you have this, the rest is an easy induction.

Take $g=f'$. Then $g^{(n-1)}=0$ in $D$. By induction, $g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-2$. 
Integrate $g$ formally and get a polynomial $G$ of degree at most $n-1$ with $G'=g$. Let $h=G-f$. Then $h'=g-f'=0$ and so $h$ is a constant, by the base case. Therefore, $f=G+h$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$.

The base case can be proved using the Cauchy–Riemann equations and the fact that $D$ is connected by paths, even staircase paths. See [this proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Zero_Derivative_implies_Constant_Complex_Function) for instance.

Comment: well one of the problems is that I don't know if I can integrate these functions as they are complex, are you saying that I can?
I see what you are saying by $f'=0$. $f'(x,y)=0\implies{u_x(x,y)=u_y(x,y)=v_x(x,y)=v_y(x,y)=0}$, and so $f$ is constant, that's pretty easy to see and prove with the mean value theorem

Comment: You lose me at "take $g=f'$". Are we allowed to claim that, because it seems to imply that we accept $g$ as a polynomial, and I don't know how we know that yet. Do you mind elucidating a bit? Sorry I'm having some trouble understanding.

Comment: @nihil, it's a proof by induction. It's the step $n-1 \implies n$.

Comment: maybe I'm not as good at induction as I thought, but if I were to proceed tabula rasa, I would agree with the base case, but my next step would be to suppose that $f$ is a function of at most $n-1$ degree and $n$-times differentiable and to consider a function $g$ that is $n+1$-times differentiable and $g^{n+1}(z)=0$. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: @nihil, the induction hypothesis gives you the result for any function that whose $n-1$-th derivative is zero. $g=f'$ is one such function.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so slow here, but what I still don't understand is how you can take $g=f'$ if we haven't demonstrated yet that it must be a polynomial. 

Maybe I'm missing something?
In induction, I know there is a base case, then the assumption that the $n$-th case work and from this we demonstrate the $n+1$-th case. What is your $n$-th case?

Comment: so I'm trying this one again with your advice above. Does this look right?
Taking for granted the base case condition.
Suppose $f(z)$ is a polynomial of
at most $n-1$ and $f^{(n-1)}(z)$
is constant. Now we consider the $n+1$ case with $g^{(n+1)}(z)=0$.
Let $G(z)=g'(z)$, then $g^{(n+1)}(z)=G^{(n)}(z)=0$, so $G^{(n)}(z)=f^{(n)}(z)$
and by inductive hypothesis, $G(z)$ is a polynomial of at least $n-1$
degree, then $G(z)=g'(z)$, hence, $\int G(z)=g(z)$, it follows that $G(z)=a_{n}z^{n-1}+\cdots+$
so its integral is $a_{n-1}z^{n}+\cdots$, so $g(z)$
is a polynomial of at least $n$ degrees.
?